# what is an appropriate way to detect errors in CAN-Bus?

Tags: c, algorithm, embedded, pic, can-bus

I am communicating with a battery that sends data with CAN Bus protocol (J1939). I use PIC 18F26K83. My goal is to display remaining state of charge on a display. For example I have value  %99 in 60 of the arrays and %1 in 40 of them then I will display %99). However, it does not look like a reliable solution because I do not know how many garbage datas I receive. Please note that I cannot use some error detection algorithms such as check sum because I have no access to microcontrollers in batter, I can only use receiver side (display).
Edit: I am aware of CRC in CAN Bus but it seems like some times it does not work since sometimes I get garbage.

Comment: " For that %in 99 60 of the arrays and %1 in 40 of them then I will dipslay 99)"  Huh? I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't know how you can do this programmatically or what exactly you want to do programmatically, but by using a *CANalyzer* (no promotion intended) tool you can analyze whatever you are getting on your CAN Bus.

Comment: @Lundin I collect received data in an array size of 100 for example. Lets imagine I received data 99 for 400 ms that makes the first 40 elements of array 99. array [1],....array[40] =99 and for 600 ms long all the data I receive is 1: array[41],....array[100] =1. In thise case I will think that the data is 1 and I will display it.

Comment: @JoeyMallone Obviously you should be using CANanalyser and not CANalyser :) These tools have such imaginative names. Just call 'em CAN listeners unless you work for Ixxat or Vector :)

Comment: @Lundin, I don't. `:)`, except that my knowledge was limited vis-à-vis other non-*Vector* CANanalysers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use CRC calculation, because CRC is calculated also at receiver side by Communication Controllers.  Thats how a CRC error is detected, for instance. To elaborate:

battery sends complete message; message gets interference on phys layer; receiver (your PIC) receives message and calculates the CRC on it; **does not match** with the CRC tag included in message; 
PIC CC will have a REC error +1, and will not ACK the message to the Battery.

**You will detect every type of CAN message error on receiver side**, except bit Error, which is also irrelevant since it will result in incomplete message.

Basically, you shouldn't be able to rely on the received CAN message content to deduce Battery level, **if the message is corrupted (garbage)**. It is simply discarded before arrives to the Application layer of your PIC.

Comment: so as I understood CAN protocol itself does this error detection. When I receive a message it is already passed the CRC calculation successfully am I right?

Comment: Correct, CAN protocol has built in error detection and error handling mechanism. 
if you read a message payload in Application, it means it passed the lower tiers without problem.

Comment: So there is no garbage that I receive, they are actual data. It is the transmitter that sends wrong data. Which means battery sends wrong data sometimes.

Comment: Yes. Maybe its another message ID. Or it is a multiplexed PDU , for which you have only one interpretation. Or simply the battery sends a cyclic message whether has information to fill it or doesn't.